# Using lat/long NAD83 in XYtool in Arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, latitude-longitude, wgs84, nad83

I have loaded a raster map that uses WGS 84. I want to locate stations/points on this map by using lat/long coordinated from an online map that uses NAD83.

Can I just copy and paste the lat/long coordinates from the online map into the XYtool in arcmap? 
Does the XY tool directly convert the lat/long to the correct decimal degree position on the map?

I tried a few samples, the stations look to be in proper positions but I am not sure because the difference in WGS84 and NAD83.

Comment: What kind of accuracy do you need? What's the cell size of the raster? Current NAD83 and WGS84 differ by about 1-2 meters. If it doesn't matter, don't worry about transforming.

Answer (score 2):

Here's What you have to do :

- 1. Set ArcMAP to NAD83.
  2. Load your XY data.
  3. Export them to a Shapefile.
  4. Project your Shapefile to wgs84 using the "Project" tool in Data managements toolbox.

Comment: The excel files contain lat/long coordinates that uses NAD83, but I have a base map that uses WGS84. After loading the XY Data, the default GCS is WGS84, do I leave it as it is or change to NAD83 (the original lat/long coods). Currently what I did is load the excel file with the lat/long cords from NAD83, in arcmap the default is WGS84 is left untouched.

Comment: Change it to NAD83 before adding the data, after you finish the procedure, you can go back to wgs84.

Comment: just to be clear, when I have added the xy data and specified x and y field, I need to edit the coordinate system of input cordinates to NAD83? and then create the shapefile in wgs84?

Comment: create the shapefile in NAD83 and then Project it

Comment: So it worked ? still have a problem? if everything is clear enough now, you can mark the answer.

Comment: still working on it now